# Cant calculate maximize function with 6 variables

Tags: function, wolfram-mathematica

I tried to calculate the maximize function of 6 variable in wolfram, but my code is always false

this is the code I've been try before:

```
[//math:Maximize//] [//math:a+b+c+d+e+f+5.34a^2-9.76ab+6.40ac-5.72ad-4.68ae-3.86af+7.78b^2-10.86bc+6.70bd+4.56be+5.98bf+5.34c^2-4.68cd-2.92ce-4.32cf+2.04d^2+3.44de+3.54df+1.61e^2+2.92ef+1.82f^2//] subject to [//math:a-b+c-d-e-f=0//] and [//math:a>=0//] and [//math:b>=0//] and [//math:c>=0//] and [//math:d>=0//] and [//math:e>=0//] and [//math:f>=0//]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this with after a fresh restart of Mathematica

```
Maximize[{a+b+c+d+e+f+5.34a^2-9.76a*b+6.40a*c-5.72a*d-4.68a*e-3.86a*f+
  7.78b^2-10.86b*c+6.70b*d+4.56b*e+5.98b*f+5.34c^2-4.68c*d-2.92c*e-
  4.32c*f+2.04d^2+3.44d*e+3.54d*f+ 1.61e^2+2.92e*f+1.82f^2,
  {a-b+c-d-e-f==0,a>=0,b>=0,c>=0,d>=0,e>=0,f>=0}},{a,b,c,d,e,f}]
```

which quickly returns

```
NMaximize:cvdiv Failed to converge to a solution. The function may be unbounded.
```

followed by

```
{3.46201*^227,
{a -> 4.18726*^113, b -> 9.23388*^112, c -> 0.,
 d -> 9.48129*^112, e -> 9.61583*^112, f -> 1.35416*^113}}
```

To more clearly see that your expression is unbounded we can add additional constraints and let `Simplify` show us an equivalent expression under those added constraints.

```
Simplify[a+b+c+d+e+f+5.34a^2-9.76a*b+6.40a*c-5.72a*d-4.68a*e-3.86a*f+
  7.78b^2-10.86b*c+6.70b*d+4.56b*e+5.98b*f+5.34c^2-4.68c*d-2.92c*e-
  4.32c*f+2.04d^2+3.44d*e+3.54d*f+1.61e^2+2.92e*f+1.82f^2,
  {a-b+c-d-e-f==0,a>=0,b>=0,c>=0,d>=0,e>=0,f>=0,a==f,b==c==d==e==0}]
```

which quickly returns

```
f (2.+3.3 f)
```